# npm run dev not working

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vue.js

I have a problem with vueJs webpack, I want to run on the server, with a command: npm run dev. But I get some error message as below.

Could anyone tell me how do I solve it?? Thank you very much!

Error message

> npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
>
> npm ERR! Failed to parse json
>
> npm ERR! Unexpected token / while parsing '{
>
> npm ERR!   "name": "vue-loader-demo",
>
> npm ERR!   "versio'
>
> npm ERR! File: /Users/sylvia/Documents/FE/Practice/vue/vue-loader-
>
> demo/package.json
>
> npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
>
> npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
>
> npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file.
>
> JSON.parse
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/sylvia/.npm/_logs/2018-04-17T12_39_56_372Z-debug.log

Here is the package.json

```
{
 "name": "vue-loader-demo",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "main.js",
 "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot" 
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

> module.exports={
>
> entry:'./main.js',
>
> output:{
>
> ```
>  path:_dirname，
>
>  filename:‘'bundle.js'’
> ```
>
> }
>   }

File structure

> |-index.html
>
> |-main.js
>
> |-App.vue
>
> |-package.json
>
> |-webpack.config.js

Comment: Seems to be some problem with package.json, recheck the file

Comment: It might be that there's a problem with your webpack.config.js file. Could you try posting this for us to see?

Comment: @Alex Mulchinock 

Here is the webpack.config.js file

module.exports={

  entry:'./main.js',

  output:{
     path:_dirname，
     filename:‘'bundle.js'’
  }
}

Comment: Please add code to your question. It's difficult to read in comments!

Comment: @Alex Mulchinock sorry, the question is updated

Comment: `filename:‘'bundle.js'’` doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue you're having is caused by the additional backticks in your webpack.config.js file.

Change this: `filename:‘'bundle.js'’`
To this: `filename:'bundle.js'`

Assuming I am correct - an error triggered here will cause the script referenced in the package.json to fail, which would result in webpack no longer seeing valid JSON (as it is seeing part JSON, part error).

This would potentially explain the "**npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.**" error message in your log.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what just fixed it for me:
Make sure your current directory is correct. When running create next / react / vue apps they will create a new folder in which your package.json file / scripts (and every other important file) are located, be sure to cd into that folder before running npm run dev.

Answer (score -2):

I used http://package-json-validator.com/ to check your file, 
problem is **author cannot be empty**:
    errors:["author field should have name"]

Answer (score -2):

Follow these steps as `npm install && npm run dev` is not working in laravel

1. `composer require laravel/ui --dev`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run dev`

***Do not use*** `npm install && npm run dev`

and if you have another problem go to path and change this

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
```

Comment: Please don't answer something else when somebody has already answered 2 years ago (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49879922/1717031). Mostly when your answer will not works. Here the problem is clearly a syntax error in webpack.config.js, not the way @sylvia uses npm.